# in C# calling from dll a C function with both wchar and char

Tags: c#

I do this when everything is char:

```
class call_dll
{
    [DllImport("my.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int myfunc(string aTitle, string aMessage);
}
```

but how can I do if aTitle is wchar and aMessage char ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `MarshalAsAttribute` like this:

```
class call_dll
{
    [DllImport("my.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int myfunc(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string aTitle,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]  string aMessage);
}
```

See the [docs for the `UnmanagedType` enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype.aspx) for reference.